# Pressing delete draft or save draft and the mail preview screen doesn't disappear. IOS Phonegap

Tags: ios, iphone, email, cordova

I am currently developing a Phonegap application for both IOS & Android.
The problem (wall) I have come up against is that when I open a generated .pdf file in my app and get the standard "Select Your Application" IOS Pop-Up, selecting Adobe Reader will fire Reader up as a new instance (which can be closed as/when). But if I select Mail It fires up in the same instance, and there is no way back to my application (save for closing and restarting).

This is a screengrab of how my app looks once mail is opened, as you can see the cancel button gives limited options (sorry not enough rep points to post image here).

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2068157/5375252/b768577c-805f-11e4-9f43-e2026d5800da.PNG

I am currently using Fileopener2 and have raised the issue over on the Github, but I am wondering if it is simply IOS related regarding the Mail app.

I have tried using in app browser and injecting code but again the mail app just overlays the inappbrowser and its "done" Button, meaning I still cant return to my app.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am using IOS 8.1.2 - Phonegap v3.6.3 and the Fileopener2 Plugin: https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2 also tried Cordova-bridge/open plugin: github.com/cordova-bridge/open/

Comment: What happens when you select "delete draft"?

Comment: What other options would you expect on cancel? The app can either keep your PDF or discard it ... I can not think of anything else

Comment: @Paulw11 Nothing, as far as I can tell, I can send the mail OK and verify by actually opening a standalone instance of Mail.

Comment: @dogsgod. I was using that as an example of what choices I have === Not a lot.Although I would at least expect a cancel button to close and cancel.

Comment: When you cancel something needs to be done with your draft. It could either be saved or be dismissed. The latter is probably what you expect to happen automatically as that is closing and doing nothing, but how should iOS know? What other option would you expect?

Comment: @dogsgod when I cancel an app that has taken control of my app I suppose I expect it to cancel the job in hand, know that its not needed for that job anymore and close. Anyway the problem I have is not the options or what they can or can not do. The problem is I am locked out of my app by the IOS mail app.

Comment: you choose save draft or delete draft, and then the mail screen should disappear

Comment: @jcesarmobile Should being the operative word and as I expected by pressing a Cancel button. But unfortunately this is not the case. For some reason it simply won't let me return back to my app without a close/restart.

Comment: so edit your question to make clear what your problem is. You press delete draft or save draft and the mail preview screen doesn't disappears. And a link to the plugin might be helpful too

Comment: @jcesarmobile I will edit now, but until you mentioned it I didn't know that 'should' of been the case. Thankyou.

Comment: more questions. Which xcode version are you using? iOS version where it happens? it seems that there was a bug like this on iOS 8 betas, but it was fixed on the final release. And there was another bug like this if you use xcode 5. So using xcode 6 and iOS 8 final should fix your problem.

Comment: IOS 8.1.2, I am using notepad++ :) & Phonegap build, so this could be a possible Phonegap issue?

Comment: Just to add...I have also tried another file opening plugin: https://github.com/cordova-bridge/open/issues and I am having the same problem, which does lead me to believe this is a lot deeper than a plugin issue.